# Objective-C Phone Number Textfield with Country Code

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I want to create a textfield with country code. User is not able to change counrty code so the code must be passive on textfield. 
Anyone has any idea?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn4af.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with UITextField's leftview.
For your info,

```
            UILabel *countryCodeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, theCell.textfield.frame.size.height)];
            countryCodeLabel.text = @"    0090"; 
            [countryCodeLabel sizeToFit];
            theCell.textfield.leftView = countryCodeLabel;
            theCell.textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Link](https://github.com/chronotruck/FlagPhoneNumber) from Github, which will provide you phone number textfield with a fancy country code picker.

And it provides you delegate methods when a country is selected, when the phone number is valid or not and you can get phone number in severals formats.